# (Android) action on a certain page - webView

Tags: java, android, webview

I would like to know if there is a way to know which page I am on and perform an action on a certain page and not on other

I have a webview which the main page is login (www.page.com/login) and when you enter send me to another page (www.page.com/home) I would like to know how to detect the page and make an action.

example: when you enter (www.page.com/home) show a floating button

I hope and explained myself well :) regards

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should be pretty straight if i assume this right. you just have to override below method and match the Uri or simple string.

```
   private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.page.com/home")) {
                // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
             startActivity(intent);
             return true;
        }
    }
}
```